# Adding custom data attributes rails image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to add data-description and data-title for galleria in my rails application but I can't see how to do this with the image tag. So far I have this:

```
<div id="galleria">
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
     <%= image_tag entry.filename, :title => "title", :class => "class", :data-description => entry.caption, :data-title => entry.caption  %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
```

But this raises the undefined local variable or method `description' error, so how would I do this in rails 3?

Comment: Can you wrap those in `:html => {}`?

Comment: I couldn't get this working in Rails 2 but good thinking.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The correct syntax for this is

```
<%= image_tag entry.filename, :title => "title", :class => "class", :data => { :description => entry.caption, :title => entry.caption }  %>
```

Comment: Why isn't that specified in the docs? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Answer (score 2):

As of rails 5.1, this syntax should work:

```
<%= image_tag entry.filename, title: "title", class: "class", data: {description: entry.caption, title: entry.caption} %>
```

Read more about attributes you can include in your `image_tag` under examples: [**rails api docs**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).