# Creating custom data attribute in Rails image_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to add a custom data attribute to a Rails image_tag to allow my jQuery to function.

First, I am starting with an image_tag like so:

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", class: "icon js-icon") %>
```

Second, for my jQuery, I need the image_tag to trigger an event, and I want it to include a data attribute like the one I am using for a button here:

```
<button class="icon js-icon" data-icon-text="Random">Icon graphic</button>
```

Adding the class attribute is easy, but I will need the data-icon-text to function as an attribute too for the data to be displayed after a .hover.

Based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066830/adding-custom-data-attributes-rails-image-tag), I tried to modify the image_tag:

```
 <%= image_tag("randomv1.png", :class "icon js-icon" :data => { :icon-text => "Random" }) %>
```

Since this is delivering an error, can I create that custom attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this:

You have to revised the class need `=>`. Then, you have to change `:icon-text` into string `"icon-text"`.

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", :class => "icon js-icon", :data => { "icon-text" => "Random" }) %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", :class => "icon js-icon", "data-icon-text" => "Random") %>
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Checking this as the answer. Both examples you provided work, and the arrow was key to preventing an error.

Answer (score 0):

`:icon-text` is not a valid ruby name, just use `:icon_text` and rails will do the `magic` for you, also the arrow `=>` is missed for `class` attribute

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", :class => "icon js-icon" :data => { :icon_text => "Random" }) %>
```

You can also use the same format as your example:

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", class: "icon js-icon" data: { icon_text: "Random" }) %>
```

Edit (Correction):

```
<%= image_tag("randomv1.png", class: "icon js-icon", data: { icon_text: "Random" }) %>
```