# Using data attribute with rails image_tag and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading, haml

I am trying to use [Echo.js](https://toddmotto.com/echo-js-simple-javascript-image-lazy-loading/) lazyloader.

To do so, I need to use a data attribute which will contain the path to my image to lazy load, such as:

```
<img src="/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="" data-echo="/assets/images/myImage.jpg">
```

I am using rails and haml. According to several answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856636/creating-custom-data-attribute-in-rails-image-tag), I should translate the plain html by: (but they don't specify what happens when the data links to an image path)

```
= image_tag("placeholder.png", :data => { "echo" => "/assets/images/myImage.jpg"})
```

OR

```
= image_tag("placeholder.png", "data-echo" => "/assets/images/myImage.jpg")
```

The placeholder.png image is displayed but myImage is never loaded.

When using the inspector, it doesn't seem that the myImage path is recognised as a path to an image.

> Any ideas? Alternatively if you could suggest a lazy loader that
>   doesn't rely on data- attributes and works with rails and haml, this
>   would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the rails assets helper on your placeholder too

```
= image_tag("placeholder.png", data: { "echo" => image_path("myImage.jpg") })
```